# Change Set not deploying

Tags: change-set

I'm wondering if anyone else is having an issue with change sets today?  I have created two change sets and deployed them to production.  This was about 6 hours ago and they are still not there.

I have never had an issue where they were longer than 30 minutes.  Just wondering if there is a salesforce issue.  thanks!!!

Comment: If that's the case you are observing, you should reach out to SF support then.

Comment: Several of our clients across different instances are reporting this, so likely a Salesforce issue

Comment: I have submitted a case.  But I have basic support so I won’t probably hear back until after it’s resolved

Comment: and I don't see anything on trust.salesforce.com

Comment: Just found that its a known issue:  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001FSx8QAG

Comment: Issue appears to be fixed.